# Spring Boot crash "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I imported a Spring Boot project from a friend (which works on his computer) but when I run it through my IntelliJ I get the following error (pom.xml includes dependencies like Web, JPA, JDBC, MySql Connector and it was all created by SpringInitializr so no errors anywhere - not even in syntax). I CAN ASSURE THAT I NEED TO DOWNLOAD SOMETHING INTO MY MACHINE, BUT IDK WHAT:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=52868...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication at 
    springboot.try2.SecondOneDbApplication.main(SecondOneDbApplication.java:11)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
        org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` should ring a bell... how are you running it?

Comment: Can you specifically state here how you run this ?

Comment: [Please format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Well, IntelliJ - Click Run on the class with Main method in it!
`NoClassDefFoundError` -> I actually checked errors related to it, people said check your pom.xml - i have the necessary dependencies